# LaTeX figure position center of page AFTER text

Tags: floats

I'd like to know how to position my LaTeX figure in the middle of the page.

However, I've written an abstract at the top of the page, so essentially, I'd like to position it in the center of the remaining space.

The abstract itself is only a few lines long, and after that I have the following:

```
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \center
    \includegraphics[width=5in]{diagrams/31.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

which isn't quite right. I'd hugely appreciate any help and advice!

Comment: please provide more information, like the height of the image and what "isn't quite right" with your approach. in the best case add the complete source code!

Comment: and please add formatting to your code, I can't do it since an edit has to contain characters.

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to this. I've specified that the image is 5 inches wide, and it's more or less a square diagram. Can you please specify what you mean by 'adding formatting'?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand but if have understood correctly then perhaps this could be worth a try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\ldots

  \vfill
  \begin{center}    
      \includegraphics [width=5 in] {diagrams/31.jpg}
  \end{center}
  \vfill

\end{document}
```

Which looks like:
[image]

Just remove the `[demo]` part to get the actual graphics.

Comment: hmm, that doesn't seemed to have made a difference. Is there a way to manually specify spacing between the top and bottom of the figure instead?

Comment: @AliceChen those `vfill` _are_ manually specifying the space. Please edit your question to have a _complete_ (small) document that shows the problem. Use `\rule{2cm}{1cm}` or similar in your example instead of `\includegraphics`  so that your example runs without needing extra graphic files.

Comment: Edited to show complete example